# Send fee tokens to non-zero address SOLIDITY

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I have a fee on any transaction of my ERC20 token and I want to redistribute a percent of that amount to all addresses that have a non-zero balance equally. I have used mapping in order to associate a balance to each address. Also, I can't seem to be able to find the total amount of addresses that hold my token. Is there any way to find that number as well in order to easily divide the total amount equally? Thanks!

`mapping (address => uint) balances;`

Answer (score 0):

A `mapping` [doesn’t](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/security-considerations.html#clearing-mappings) have some `.size` or `.length` property that you can query to know how many non-zero entries it contains. You can put values and you can get them back, but you cannot ask it how many entries it contains (… a bit like the human brain actually.)

So if you need to know that information, you need to track it yourself by maintaining a counter which you increment when an entry becomes non-zero, and decrement when an entry goes back to zero.